# validates with context not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this validation in my `User` model

```
with_options(on: :custom) do |v|
  v.validate :password_is_valid
  v.validate :email_is_valid
  ...
  other validations
end
```

and I'm saving the user in the controller as this

```
user = new_from_params
user.setup_activation && user.save!(context: :custom)
```

but the `v.validate :password_is_valid` is not working. the method (lives in User model) is not being called, but other validations (e.g. `v.validates :eula, acceptance: true` are working fine
Is there other way to call validations in the model when using contexts?

**EDIT**

Ok, I noticed something very weird.

I have these 2 validations:

```
with_options(on: :qzr) do |v|
```

and

```
with_options(on: :update_data) do |v|
```

during the validation, if I call `user.validate! :qzr`, it does not work, but works if I do `user.validate! :update_data`. BUT (here is the weird part), if I move `with_options(on: :update_data)` on top of `with_options(on: :qzr)` I get the reverse behaviour: `qzr` works but `update_data` always return true, even though the user is invalid

**Edit2 **

I noticed this only happens on RSpec. Calling the API outside test works perfectly

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Did you find a solution, on rspec?

Comment: I think just stop testing activerecord validation because it makes no sense